# Why are my cells counted as different cell blocks?

Tags: prison-architect

I've tried rebuilding cells and the foundations of the cell blocks, but my cells keep getting counted as individual cell blocks. I've posted images of the cell block in deployment and live mode. What am I missing?

Here's an image of the deployment.
[image: Here's an image of the deployment]
<sub>(source: [steamusercontent.com](http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/264973202197857944/5CFD0B4E8B55059E13F5985969CA95921A971B2C/))</sub>

http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=761803133

Here's an image of live mode.
[image: Here's an image of live mode]
<sub>(source: [steamusercontent.com](http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/264973202197853234/8E4F2FA3BCAFA9DB5C713AB83D237C6C84CB1AC2/))</sub>

http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=761802482

Comment: Does reloading the save solve your problem? If not: could you share the prison via the steam workshop so we can look at the prison in more detail?

Comment: I've tried exiting the game, saving, and reloading. How can I share the prison?

Comment: [Esc] > Extras > Prison Sharing (Steam) > Publish this prison. Then share the steam url.

Comment: Thank you so much! Here's the link: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=761830146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm that tries to group up cells can't handle the particular shape you are using there. Since it can't find a group of cells to make a cell block, it will make the larger structure it can find a cell block. I think in this case it has to do with the family cells not being recognised as cells for a cell block.

For the middle cell block, add a large jail door and a small jail door to block off the common room. They can be locked open, but now the cells are grouped together.

[image: Middle cell block]

For the lower cell block, block off the lower part. Alternatively, dezone the lower part.

[image: Lower cell block]

[image: Dezoned lower block]

In general, try to block off a group of cells with jail doors, and minimise the number of other rooms in that block.

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed the bottom two cells. I can't seem to fix the first one cell block even though I placed doors to block of the halls. The bottom row of family cells are still seen as separate cell blocks. [First Cell Block](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=762139319)